# How can hide input with crud-type "relation_hidden" - Codeigniter (Grocery Crud Library)

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm using Codeigniter and also Grocery Crud as library.

The problem apear when i want to hide 1 inputs. 
It's about `created_by` which have set relation.

All works find with `'crud_type' => 'hidden'`.

But when you set relation and try to hide it `crud_type` become `relation_hidden`. All fields with `relation_hidden` is shown in add page.

I have no idea why. Can someone help me with an advice?

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to hide field which has `set_relation`, but this workaround might be applicable in your case:

```
if( $crud->getstate() == 'edit' ) 
{
    $crud->set_relation('created_by ', 'author', 'author');
}
else
{
    $crud->field_type('created_by ', 'hidden', 'default_value');
}
```

Comment: Ty for your answer but still not working.
'created_by' has foregn key with users.
If i remove hide input setting 'field_type('created_by ', 'hidden', 'default_value');' it becomes dropdown select with available users.
Also when i set hide input setting, it still apear as input type='text'.